# Moving a bitmap object using onscreen navigation buttons

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bitmap

I need some help.

I have a bitmap image placed on screen and 4 navigational buttons (Up, Down, etc.). Now I want to move that image using those buttons, of course the image will continue moving as long as the button is pressed and the image will only stop once the user releases his finger. Now I'm not sure if the code below works as intended so this is why I came here.

Here's the code:

Here's the image:

```
//SRC-Rect Values
        int playerLeft, playerTop, playerBottom, playerRight;
```

Here's the image's location on-screen:

```
//DEST-Rect Values
        int destBottom, destRight, destTop, destLeft;
```

Here are the buttons:

```
//Arrow Buttons to move the player
        up = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonUp);
        right = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRight);
        down = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDown);
        left = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft);

        //Up Button
        up.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                while (true){

                    velocityY++;

                    destTop += topMove;
                    destBottom += bottomMove;
                }
            }
        });

        //Right Button
        right.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                while (true){

                    velocityX++;

                    destRight += rightMove;
                    destLeft += leftMove;
                }
            }
        });

        //Down Button
        down.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                while (true){

                    velocityY--;

                    destTop -= topMove;
                    destBottom -= bottomMove;
                }
            }
        });

        //Left Button
        left.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                while (true){

                    velocityX--;

                    destRight -= rightMove;
                    destLeft -= leftMove;
                }
            }
        });
```

Velocity X and Y are the speed of the image while moving,
and the movement button values are the amount of pixels they need to move when the button is touched.

```
//Arrow Buttons
private Button up, right, down, left;

//Movement Button Values
public static int topMove = -20;
public static int rightMove = -20;
public static int bottomMove = 20;
public static int leftMove = 20;

//Movement speed
public static int velocityX = 0;
public static int velocityY = 0;
```

Here's the XML Layout:

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonUp"
    android:background="@drawable/up"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonLeft"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonLeft"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonLeft" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonLeft"
    android:background="@drawable/left"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonRight"
    android:background="@drawable/right"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonDown"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonDown"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonDown" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/buttonDown"
    android:background="@drawable/down"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonUp"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonUp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) to render the bitmap you want to move. They can be used to redraw your bitmap on the new position you specify.

**Refer this:**
https://makingthechain.wordpress.com/2013/12/17/how-to-move-a-bitmap-using-android-canvas/

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the Canvas. [Canvas in Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html). It is incredibly helpful for moving objects, like this, around a screen. Another helpful place is the Android Documentation for Canvas. However, the following link is a tutorial on drawing an object onto the canvas and moving it around. Just use your onClickListener's to update the position versus the "if" statement checks by adding your button movement values. [Tutorial on the Canvas](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/bouncing-a-ball-on-androids-canvas/)

```
//Movement Button Values
public static int topMove = -20;
public static int rightMove = -20;
public static int bottomMove = 20;
public static int leftMove = 20;
```

I hope that helps. I would also recommend using a gaming engine if you are trying to do more than simple quick interactions. Unity3D is a highly popular engine with tons of documentation and free tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote example for you.
Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move_left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="left"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="right"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move_down"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="down"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/move_up"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="up"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment class

```
public class DebugFragment extends Fragment implements 
View.OnTouchListener {

 public static final int PERIOD = 30; //move view every PERIOD milliseconds until ACTION_UP event is coming

public static final int STEP = 10; //dx pixels

private View mImage;

private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

private boolean isNeedMoving;

enum MOVE {
    LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN, UP
}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_debug, container, false);

    mImage = rootView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    View leftMoveBtn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.move_left);
    View rightMoveBtn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.move_right);
    View downMoveBtn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.move_down);
    View upMoveBtn = rootView.findViewById(R.id.move_up);

    leftMoveBtn.setOnTouchListener(this);
    rightMoveBtn.setOnTouchListener(this);
    downMoveBtn.setOnTouchListener(this);
    upMoveBtn.setOnTouchListener(this);


    return rootView;
}


@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


    int maskedAction = event.getActionMasked();

    final MOVE actionMove = getActionMove(v.getId());

    switch (maskedAction) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            isNeedMoving = true;
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    moveView(actionMove);
                    if (isNeedMoving) {
                        mHandler.postDelayed(this, PERIOD);
                    }
                }
            });
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            isNeedMoving = false;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;

    }
    return true;
}

private MOVE getActionMove (@IdRes int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case R.id.move_left:
            return MOVE.LEFT;
        case R.id.move_right:
            return MOVE.RIGHT;
        case R.id.move_down:
            return MOVE.DOWN;
        case R.id.move_up:
            return MOVE.UP;
        default:
            return MOVE.LEFT;
    }
}

private void moveView(MOVE action) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mImage.getLayoutParams();
    switch (action) {
        case LEFT:
            layoutParams.leftMargin -= STEP;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            layoutParams.leftMargin += STEP;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            layoutParams.topMargin += STEP;
            break;
        case UP:
            layoutParams.topMargin -= STEP;
            break;

    }
    mImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
}
}
```

So if you need moving image by finger swipe then you can implement Drag and Drop events http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html